# ui grid Filter and sorting not working when cellTemplate used

Tags: angularjs, filter, ui-grid

I am using `ui.grid` where some of the columns are populated with `cellTemplate`. It populates the value correctly, but the sorting and filtering is not working. Do I need to do anything with the sorting/filtering logic ?

Issue is recreated @ Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/JscrG3EJiTlnVa0t9DjH , both Age and Balance columns sorting and filtering is not working.

```
 this.grdColDefs = [
            {
                name: 'Age',
                width: 90,
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.calcAge(row.entity)}}</div>',
                headerCellClass: 'my-cell-header',
            }
        ];
```

Comment: giving cellTemplate doesnot affect filtering and sorting may be some other issue can you provide fiddle for exixting code

Comment: I got where is problem is that in view whatever is visible is not what is present in your row entity for example in you grid one year is visible bot in your row entity only one is present so when you filter with one it should be working when you filter with one year it may not be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved when I use `field` to point to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in making data for cell template 
I will share you two code pens one with working filter one without working filter and will try to explain difference in both why at one place it is working and why at other it is not working

When we make cell template like this as in your case

```
 cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.calcAge(row.entity)}}</div>',
```

In this case filter will not work because whatever is displayed in grid is different from what is actually present in row.entity

looking at your problem statement i mocked a sample grid where filter is not working
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/zKmVVO

if we want to make our grid using this implementation still filter should work then we can change filter logic like this

```
 $scope.singleFilter = function( renderableRows ){
 var matcher = new RegExp($scope.filterValue);
 renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
  var match = false;
  ['name','age'].forEach(function( field ){
    if ( row.entity[field].match(matcher) ){
      match = true;
    }
    if(field =='age'){
     //this is new if block to handle the case for filtering not working
       var currData =$scope.calcAge(row.entity)
       if (currData.match(matcher) ){
      match = true;
    }
       }
  });
  if ( !match ){
    row.visible = false;
  }
});
return renderableRows;
 };
```

**To fix this issue**

What i did is whatever you want to display in grid same data should be present in your gridOptions.data array so before building grid make gridOptions.data as you need here is working demo where filter is working
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/rrqgzy

Now please observe the difference in both case

New cell template is this

```
 cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{row.entity.age}}</div>',
            headerCellClass: 'my-cell-header'
```

In this case whatever is visible in grid is same as our data in gridOptions.data

I tried to understand your problem and explain it in best possible way even if you have any question feel free to ask, i have made change in custom filter similarly we can make custom sorting work

Comment: This does not make sense, the `calcAge()` function is what I need to call to get required data.

Comment: If we cant change this implementation then we need to change our customized filter logic please look for change filter logic its working